# Prevent spData::world countries from wrapping around the map / cropping map area

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am making a map using `sf::world`, where I would only like to plot Europe, Africa, Asia and Ocenia:

```
library(sf)
map = spData::world %>%
    dplyr::filter(!continent %in% c("South America", "North America", "Antarctica"))

ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data=map, aes(geometry=geom))
```

[image]

As it stands, bits of Russia and Oceania are wrapping around and making a lot of empty space on the figure.

I have tried various combinations of `st_crop` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56547120/5784757), to crop out the whitespace doing:

```
st_crop(map, xmin=-30, xmax=180, ymin=-180, ymax=180)
```

But it seems to return a blank map with no geometries. I feel like the solution is a simple use of this function, but I can't get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the approach proposed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67977330/7756889

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

map = spData::world %>%
  dplyr::filter(!continent %in% c("South America", "North America", "Antarctica"))

# Russia only will not do; Fiji also crosses the antimeridean...
rossiya <- subset(map,  iso_a2 %in% c("RU", "FJ"))

pacified_rossiya <- st_shift_longitude(rossiya)

rest_of_world <- subset(map, !iso_a2 %in% c("RU", "FJ"))

map2 <- rbind(pacified_rossiya,
                rest_of_world) 

plot(st_geometry(map2))
```

[image]

It seems to work the best in base plot though, and crashes when applied to ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tmap`:

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(tmap)

# data
map = spData::world %>%
  dplyr::filter(!continent %in% c("South America", "North America", "Antarctica"))

# plot
tm_shape(map, bbox = c(-30, -60, 180, 90)) + 
  tm_polygons()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Check the help page of `?tm_shape` for more details.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @Jindra Lacko, the approach presented here simply applies a rectangular filter to the map without resolving the problems near the antimeridian.

Comment: You have cut off Chukotka from Russia and split Fiji in half; the wrap around antimeridean is not resolved but hidden by the bbox

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I added a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's a good answer but I can't accept it since I kinda need the whole of Russia to be in the figure.